# How can get an item by its name from the list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to select an item from the list by its name. I tried with the "Select", but getting an error that "Element is not currently visible and so may not interacted with". The following is my script using Select:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='miscinfo_div']/ol/li[1]/div/fieldset/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li"));

 Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("companionPositionSelect")));
 select.selectByVisibleText("Bottom1-Top1");
```

I also tried with List. It selects the item by its Index, but I need to select an item only by its text. I guess List does not have an option to select an item by its text. This is my script for the List:

```
 List<WebElement> availableCompPositions = driver
        .findElements(By
            .xpath("//input[@id='companionPositionSelect_a_search']//following::div[1]/ul/li"));
    // select Bottom1-Top1 and add in the SELECTED menu
    availableCompPositions.get(4).click();
```

Also attached is HTML of the page.[image]

HTML:

```
<div style="" id="miscinfo_div" class="toggler">
<ol>
<li>
    <span>17.</span>
        <label class="shufflelabel">
            <div id="companionPositions_label">
                    <b> Companion Positions </b>
            </div>
        </label>

        <div>
            <fieldset class="shuttle_fieldset">
            <legend></legend>

        <div class="shuffle-box">
        <select multiple="" id="companionPositionSelect" class="select2side" name="companionPositionSelect" style="display: none;">

            <option value="20408" title="Bottom-BottomLeft-BottomRight">Bottom-BottomLeft-BottomRight</option>

            <option value="20391" title="Bottom-Middle-Top">Bottom-Middle-Top</option>

            <option value="20382" title="Bottom-Top" selected="selected">Bottom-Top</option>

            <option value="20392" title="Bottom1-Middle1-Top1" selected="selected">Bottom1-Middle1-Top1</option>

            <option value="20383" title="Bottom1-Top1">Bottom1-Top1</option>

            <option value="20393" title="Bottom2-Middle2-Top2">Bottom2-Middle2-Top2</option>

        </select>

    </div>
```

Comment: Provide html code not image

Comment: and is `selectByValue()` an option?

Comment: Yes, but it generates an error that there is no such option. I added HTML above. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the error I am assuming you are trying to perform an action too soon. The following program should wait max 10s explicitly for the element to be located

Added `explicit` wait to wait until the element exist

```
//explicit wait
By byCss = By.cssSelector("#companionPositionSelect>option[value='20383']");
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byCss));
        element.click();
```

Comment: Click on the `div` then click the `select` and use wait and do you get `NoSuchElement` exception?

Comment: Yes            NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with value: 20383. I have an item with number 20383 in the list.

Comment: `JavascriptExecutor java = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        java.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"#companionPositionSelect>option[value='20383']\").setAttribute('selected','selected');");`

Comment: @familyGuy try the javascript snippet above

Comment: I greatly appreciate your efforts, but now its giving WebDriverException: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70273/discussion-between-saifur-and-familyguy).

Comment: A solution provided by Saifur. It works!        List<WebElement> availableCompPositions = driver 
    .findElements(By 
    .xpath("//input[@id='companionPositionSelect_a_search']//following::div[1]/ul/li")); 

    for (WebElement webElement: availableCompPositions){ 

    if (webElement.getText().contains("Bottom1-Top1")){ 
    webElement.click(); 
    } 
    }